# How to reject calls if custom thread-pool queue is full?

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework, akka, threadpool

Using Play Framework 2.5, how to make custom thread pool reject tasks if the pool and the queue fully busy?

Using next configuration of default and custom thread-pools.

```
akka {
  actor {
    default-dispatcher {
      throughput=1
      executor="thread-pool-executor"
      thread-pool-executor {
        fixed-pool-size=off
        core-pool-size=5
        max-pool-size=10
        task-queue-size=5
      }
    }
  }
}

contexts {
  custom {
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
    throughput = 1
    thread-pool-executor {
      fixed-pool-size=10
      task-queue-size=1
    }
  }
}
```

And the next controller:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.Result;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import static play.mvc.Results.ok;

public class TestController {
  private final ExecutionContextExecutor executor;

  @Inject
  public TestController(ActorSystem actorSystem) {
    this.executor = actorSystem.dispatchers().lookup("contexts.custom");
  }

  public CompletionStage<Result> call() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::task, executor);
  }

  private Result task() {
    Logger.info("Task started");
    sleep(5000);
    Logger.info("----- Task completed ----- ");
    return ok("ok");
  }

  private static void sleep(long millis) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
}
```

I expect that after 10 requests, they'll start being rejected by the custom thread-pool, but instead, they are executed on the default pool.

```
[application-contexts.custom-14] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-16] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-15] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-20] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-19] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-17] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-21] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-18] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-22] INFO  application - Task started
[application-contexts.custom-23] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO  application - Task started
[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11] INFO  application - Task started
```

That means that the default pool will be busy and won't process other requests unless it completes all heavy tasks. 
I want my custom pool to reject tasks if the pool is full and the queue full as well. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your execution context programmatically with the desired logic for example with the `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ThreadPoolExecutor(...))`.
You may also implement your own `akka.dispatch.ExecutorServiceConfigurator` and specify its fully qualified class name in the config: [docs here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.16/dispatchers.html?language=scala)

```
my-thread-pool-dispatcher {
  # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
  type = Dispatcher
  # What kind of ExecutionService to use
  executor = "<Class name of the configurator>"

}
```